# Visualization of a conical helix and a conical spiral

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d

Both, conical helix and conical spiral, have a continuously decreasing radius.

How can I visualize the difference between the two? No need for equations. Any explanation in 3D plots would be of great help. On the internet, both the plots appear to be same.

Comment: I don't think there is a difference, but maybe you have a reason to believe otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conical helix need not meet at a point and can have a minimum( or maximum i suppose) radius, whereas a conical spiral must start at a point.
A conical helix will reverse the direction of change in radius once it passes the origin too, kind of like a stint frayed outward at both ends.